# add prefix in shell script to json resonse

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I want to add some prefix to the field from output of hitting endpoint.

**file.sh**

```
result=$(curl -s <someEndpoint>)
echo $result
```

I have a cronjob to hit that endpoint regularly;

```
* * * * * /root/file.sh | jq .field > /root/file.txt 2>&1
```

I need to add "start" to the .field.
I created another file2.sh:

```
prefix="start"
val=$(cat /root/file.txt)
concat="${prefix}${val}"
echo $concat
```

the output looks like:
start"value from file.txt"

I want "start value from file.txt". how can I do that?

Comment: Where that value comes from? file.txt?

Comment: @LMC `val` comes from `file.txt`. I am reading this can be handled by `jq` itself, but not sure how can I do that.

Comment: You should quote the variable: `echo "$result"`.

Comment: Or get rid of the variable entirely. Just run `curl` and its output will be written to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the better solution would be to use `jq -r .field` to output plaintext instead of a JSON string, but since you explicitly want to work with json, you can use `jq` again:

```
$ echo '"string"' | jq '"start" + .'
"startstring"
```